# Passing data from ajax to mvc controller - null parameter error

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I got jquery ajax request on client side and asp mvc on server side. 
I send this to the server 
[image]
But I didn't get temperatureRanges 
[image]
Do somebody know why?

ajax-code:

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            async: false,
            url: "/PVTMethods/StandartModelResult",
            data: JSON.stringify(dataForSend),           
            async: true,
            success: function(data) {
                //TODO Реализовать обработку результата
            },
            error: function(data) {
                console.log("Error" + data);
            },
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        });
```

Model on server:

```
 public class DefaultRanges {
        public virtual double Start { get; set; } //начало отрезка
        public virtual double End { get; set; } //конец отрезка
        public virtual double Samples { get; set; } //шаги
    }

public class TemperatureDefaultRanges:DefaultRanges {}
public struct InputDataModel
    {
        /// <summary> решаемая задача </summary>
        public Tasks task;
        /// <summary>  данные по давлению </summary>
        public PressureDefaultRanges pressureRanges;
        /// <summary>  данные по температуре </summary>
        public TemperatureDefaultRanges temperatureRanges;
        ////в pvt настройки по ctrl+H - ranges для отдельно взятого графика
       /// <summary>  данные по температуре </summary>
        public PlotRanges currentTaskPlotRanges;
        public double plotConstant; //либо GOR либо Pressure (зависит от задачи)

    }
```

Comment: whats JSON.stringify(dataForSend) print ?

Comment: Change your fields to properties (add getters and setters) so the `DefaultModelBinder` can **set** them.

Comment: @user1428716 `"{"method":"eStanding","model":{"task":"ePb","temperatureRanges":{"Start":200,"End":1000,"Samples":30}},"constants":{"ProducedGOR":500,"OilGravity":35,"SeparatorGasGravity":0.7,"StockTankOilGravity":0.84956,"WaterSalinity":20}}"`

Comment: @StephenMuecke post answer please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the fields in `InputDataModel` properties by adding `{ get; set; }` so the the `DefaultModelBinder` can **set** the value of the properties.