# Passing data through ajax - the parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc

I got my previous question which is quite the same. 
[Passing data from ajax to mvc controller - null parameter error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29338747/passing-data-from-ajax-to-mvc-controller-null-parameter-error)

We've changed some things in interface and javascript after it. So now I get this error, when I try to pass data on server

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'method'
>   of non-nullable type 'API.PVT.Solver.Methods' for method
>   'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult
>   StandartModelResult(API.PVT.Solver.InputDataModel,
>   API.PVT.Solver.Methods, API.PVT.Solver.DefaultConstants)' in
>   'WebServices.Controllers.PVT.PVTMethodsController'. An optional
>   parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as
>   an optional parameter

Here's my client side request

```
 GetServerData:function(inputData) {
        var outputData;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "/PVTMethods/StandartModelResult",
            data: JSON.stringify(inputData),
            success: function (data) {
                outputData = data.result;
                appl.PlotData = data.result;
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log("Error" + data);
            },
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "appllication/json; charset=utf-8",
        });
        return outputData;

    }
```

[image]

Here's how json looks like:

```
"{"method":"eMcCain","model":{"task":"eBw","temperatureRanges":{"Start":200,"End":1000,"Samples":30}},"constants":{"ProducedGOR":500,"OilGravity":35,"SeparatorGasGravity":0.7,"StockTankOilGravity":0.84985,"WaterSalinity":20}}"
```

Here's server side models

```
  public class DefaultRanges
    {
        public virtual double Start { get; set; } //начало отрезка
        public virtual double End { get; set; } //конец отрезка
        public virtual double Samples { get; set; } //шаги
    }
    //константы
    public class DefaultConstants
    {
        public virtual double ProducedGOR { get; set; }
        public virtual double OilGravity { get; set; }
        public virtual double SeparatorGasGravity { get; set; }
        public virtual double StockTankOilGravity { get; set; }
        public virtual double WaterSalinity { get; set; }
    }

    //pressure rate (pisa)
    public class PressureDefaultRanges : DefaultRanges { }

    //temperature ranges (Фаренгейты если чо)
    public class TemperatureDefaultRanges : DefaultRanges { }

    public class PlotRanges : DefaultRanges
    {
        public virtual double PlotConstant { get; set; } //GOR или Pressure
    }
    // w\ pressure
    public class PlotRangesWP : PlotRanges
    {
        public virtual double Pressure { get; set; }
    }
    // w\ GOR
    public class PlotRangesWGOR : PlotRanges
    {
        public virtual double GOR { get; set; }
    }

    //решаемые задачи
    public enum Tasks { ePb, eRs, eBo, eBg, eMo, eMg, eMod, eBw, eMw, eRsw };
    //применяемые методы
    public enum Methods
    {
        eAbdulMajeed,//+
        eAlShammasi,//+
        eAlKhafaji,//+
        eAlMarhoun,//+
        eAlMarhounSA,//+
        eAlmehaideb,//+
        eAlNajjaretal,/
        eAziz,//+
        eBeal,//+
        eBeggsRobinson,//+
        eBeggsVazquez,//+
        eBergman,//+
        eDempsey,//+
        eDindorukChristman,//+
        eDoklaOsman,//+
        eElam,//+
        eElsharkawy,
        eFarshad,//+
        eGlaso,//+
        eHasan,//+
        eKartoatmodjoSchmidt,//+
        eKhairy,//+
        eKhanEtAl,//dead oil viscosity пока не нужен
        eLabediL,//+
        eLabediNA,//+
        eLasater,//+
        eLeeGonzales,//+
        eLevitanMurtha,//+
        eLucas,//+
        eMcCain,//+
        eMakary,//+
        eObomanuOkpobiri,
        eOmarTodd,//+
        eOwolabiCI,//+
        eOwolabiNS,//+
        ePetrosky,//+
        eSchlumbergerKuwait,//?  
        eStanding//+
    };




    public class InputDataModel
    {

        public Tasks task { get; set; }

        public PressureDefaultRanges pressureRanges { get; set; }

        public TemperatureDefaultRanges temperatureRanges { get; set; }

        public PlotRanges currentTaskPlotRanges { get; set; }
        public double plotConstant { get; set; } 
    }
```

Here's server side controller method

```
 public ActionResult StandartModelResult(InputDataModel model , Methods method, DefaultConstants constants = null)
        {
            SolverInit(constants);

            SetDeafultSettings(); //стандартные настройки методов
            //var method = Methods.eMcCain;
            PVTMethodsSolver.PVTSolverTaskMethodSettings(model.task, method);

            var currentResult = resultArray(model);

            return Json(new { result = currentResult, status = "ok"}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
```

What's wrong here?
It's even can't reach server now, I mean the request. What could help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change ajax code like that and it's started to work

```
GetServerData:function(inputData) {
        var outputData;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            async: false,
            url: "/PVTMethods/StandartModelResult",
            data: inputData,
           // async: true,
            success: function (data) {
                outputData = data.result;
                appl.PlotData = data.result;
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log("Error" + data);
            },
            dataType: "json",
          //  contentType: "appllication/json; charset=utf-8"
        });
        return outputData;

    }
```

Comment: For anyone else coming across this, remember that this answer is for MVC Controllers; if you are using WebAPI Controllers, this answer will not work,